# How do I make a list out of several JSON objects?

Tags: dart

Given `{foo: bar, baz: boo}` and `{foo: bar2, baz: boo2}`, how do I make a JSON list with both of the objects:

```
[
  {
    foo: bar,
    baz: boo
  },
  {
    foo: bar2,
    baz: boo2
  }
]
```

Comment: By the way, if you use JSONP, and you send a JSON list to the client, it's possible for malicious JavaScript on the page to hijack the JSON list by overriding some prototype. It's not a Dart vulnerability. It's a browser vulnerability. The web is such a weird place!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a list and append the two JSON objects to it.

```
var object1 = JSON.parse('{"foo":"bar", "baz":"boo"}');
var object2 = JSON.parse('{"foo":"bar2", "baz":"boo2"}');
var list = new List();
list..add(object1)
    ..add(object2);
```

`list` is now `[{foo: bar, baz: boo}, {foo: bar2, baz: boo2}]`